# Adding a UI in JSP application till page loaded

Tags: html, jsp

I've developed a web application. It consist of 2 pages,

- index.html
- report.jsp

In index.html, added a form with a selection option for the user input. On submit, we have redirected to report.jsp to do the actual task and render the result. The result has been published in report.jsp. Since we have added scriptlets in report.jsp and it took 1-2 minutes to complete the task and show the result. 
I would like to add a progress bar like something till the report.jsp page load completes. Could you please have someone give an idea to implement this ?

Comment: Create onload function page to create progress bar i think

Comment: @Vysakh.. yes.. you have to invoke body onaload function or  $(document).ready(function())} and in that you can create tour pogress bar

Comment: Or you can use [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)

Answer (score 0):

the following java script code will solve your problem.add some stylesheet to customize it.

```
<section>
 <h2>Task Progress</h2>
 <p>Progress: <progress id="p" max=100><span>0</span>%</progress></p>
 <script>
  var progressBar = document.getElementById('p');
  function updateProgress(newValue) {
    progressBar.value = newValue;
    progressBar.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent = newValue;
  }
 </script>
</section>
```